# Computing electric displacement

Tags: electromagnetism

I have read that when you have symmetry you can  compute the eletric  displacement field with gauss law in integral foram, since D is constant and so it comes out of the integral. 
My question is, why is it constant when you have symmetry, i understand how it works in the case of finding E by the same method, but why is D constant? How does it vector field look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field due to a point charge, which has radial symmetry, looks like this:
[image]

If I were to apply Gauss' Law in this situation, I might set up a spherical Gaussian surface around the charge. You can see that since the electric field is radially symmetric, it is always normal to the surface, and so it is "constant" in the sense that at any point on the surface, the field lines have the same orientation with respect to the surface at that point.

There is no external polarization in this situation, so displacement is simply proportional to the electric field.

Comment: So only if polarization is zero can i apply the symmetry argument?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on the polarization. If there were also a radial polarization then this would hold. Basically you need to analyze the symmetry of E + P, and in this case since P = 0 and E is symmetric it works. But P could share the symmetry as well.